# How to change default rangeselector in plotly python

Tags: python, date, plotly, date-range, rangeslider

I am using plotly(python) to implement range selector where I've created multiple buttons for selecting ranges and I want to show only one month data by default but it showing all data. My code and its output are below what changes should I make?

```
 import plotly.graph_objects as go
    
    import pandas as pd
    
    # Load data
    df = pd.read_csv(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")
    df.columns = [col.replace("AAPL.", "") for col in df.columns]
    
    # Create figure
    fig = go.Figure()
    
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date), y=list(df.High)))
    
    # Set title
    fig.update_layout(
        title_text="Time series with range slider and selectors"
    )
    
    # Add range slider
    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis=dict(
            rangeselector=dict(
                buttons=list([
                    dict(count=1,
                         label="1m",
                         step="month",
                         stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(count=6,
                         label="6m",
                         step="month",
                         stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(count=1,
                         label="YTD",
                         step="year",
                         stepmode="todate"),
                    dict(count=1,
                         label="1y",
                         step="year",
                         stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(step="all")
                ])
            ),
            rangeslider=dict(
                visible=True
            ),
            type="date"
        )
    )
    
    fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `range=[{start_date},{end_date}]` to the dictionary you're passing to the `xaxis` parameter. For example:

```
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1,
                        label="1m",
                        step="month",
                        stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=6,
                        label="6m",
                        step="month",
                        stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1,
                        label="YTD",
                        step="year",
                        stepmode="todate"),
                dict(count=1,
                        label="1y",
                        step="year",
                        stepmode="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date",
        range=["2016-01-01","2016-02-01"]
    )
)
```

[image]